# Momentum Trading platform / technology stack

Tags: software-development

We are in process of implementing momentum trading platform. 
Please provide suggestions for; technology considerations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

- python
- celery (scheduler to fetch data)
- postgresql (storage)
- pandas (trading algoritm)
- TensorFlow (if you want AI)